# Python - get text from CSS property “content” on a ::before pseudo element in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape an a few elements and return the displayed text on the webpage.  I believe I can find the elements fine through css_selectors and xpaths, but i cannot return the desired text.  Here is my program below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import threading
import pandas as pd

threadLocal = threading.local()

def instantiate_chrome():
    driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'driver', None)

    if driver is None:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('log-level=3')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'path/to/chrome', options = options)
        setattr(threadLocal, 'driver', driver)

    return driver

def search_stock(driver, stock):
    search_url = r'https://www.forbes.com/search/?q=' + stock
    driver.get(search_url)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'/html/body/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[1]').click()

def get_q_score(stock, driver):

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['stock','overall_score','quality', 'momentum','growth','technicals'])
    time.sleep(3)
    overall_score = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(r'.q-factor-total .q-score-bar__grade-label').text
    quality_score = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]').text

    return print('overall score is '+ overall_score, ' quality score is ' + quality_score)

def main(stock):
    driver = instantiate_chrome()
    print('attempting to get q score for ' + stock)
    search_stock(driver, stock)
    print('found webpage for ' + stock)
    get_q_score(stock, driver)

main('AAPL')
```

I believe the issue to be that i am attempting to scrape the text via selenium's .text method, but there is no text to scrape.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The text you are talking about - what is it? Is it text rendered in fonts or displayed in another form e.g. gifs, images, etc since your words here `but there is no text to scrape` is completely baffling. The `.text` method only returns if the element in question has that text.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 apologies. When I run this script, it returns an empty string. I was expecting it to return a string for overall_score and quality_score. I see there is visible text on the webpage.

Comment: Ok. i will look into it and update in a short time

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 thank your sorry for the awful wording.

Comment: It seems like the `path` provided to obtain the text is malformed. Can you tell me exactly what you are targetting with this `overall_score` and `quality_score` on the page?

Comment: I am specifically targeting the Q-factor score labeled ‘Top Buy’. I want the text ‘Top Buy’.

Comment: Additionally, clicking “view score details.” I want each of the classifications (Quality/Momentum/Growth/Technicals) and their associated letter rating (A,B).

Comment: Do see my answer and ask if you have any doubts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right path except for the text that you mentioned aren't actually `text`. These `texts` are actually rendered by a `CSS` property called the `content` which can only be used with the pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`. You can read [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/) on how it works if you are interested.

The text are rendered as icons; this is sometimes done by organizations to avoid sensible values being **scraped**. However, there is a way(somewhat hard) to get around this. Using `Selenium` and `javascript` you can individually target the `CSS` values of the property `content` in which it holds the values you are after.

Having looked into it for an hour this is simplest `pythonic` way of getting the values you desire

```
overall_score = driver.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('.q-score-bar__grade-label')].map(div => window.getComputedStyle(div,':before').content)") #key line in the problem
```

The code simply creates a `javascript` code that targets the `classes` of the elements and then maps the `div` elements to the values of the `CSS` properties.
This returns a list

```
['"TOP BUY"', '"B"', '"B"', '"B"', '"A"']
```

the values, corresponding in the following order

`Q-Factor Score/Quality/Momentum/Growth/Technicals`

To access the values of a list you can use a `for` loop and `indexing` to select the value. You can see more on that [here](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/)