# I am trying to extract a text from an <a> tag that has a ::before selector using selenium/python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```html
<ul class="ipc-inline-list ipc-inline-list--show-dividers ipc-inline-list--inline ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content baseAlt" role="presentation">
  <li role="presentation" class="ipc-inline-list__item"><a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/name/nm9297923/?ref_=tt_ov_st">Ashley Ballard</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="ipc-inline-list__item"><a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/name/nm8484653/?ref_=tt_ov_st">Elizabeth Cascarelli</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="ipc-inline-list__item"><a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/name/nm8160673/?ref_=tt_ov_st">Jason Alan Cook</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

I tried XPATH,CSS selectors but nothing works

```
actorname1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
'#__next > main > div > section.ipc-page-background.ipc-page-background-- 
base.TitlePage__StyledPageBackground-wzlr49-0.dDUGgO > section > div:nth-child(4) > section > section 
> div.Hero__MediaContentContainer__Video-kvkd64-2.kmTkgc > div.Hero__ContentContainer-kvkd64- 
10.eaUohq > div.Hero__MetaContainer__Video-kvkd64-4.kNqsIK > 
div.PrincipalCredits__PrincipalCreditsPanelWideScreen-hdn81t-0.iGxbgr > ul > li.ipc-metadata- 
list__item.ipc-metadata-list-item--link > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a'))).text
```

**LOOKS UGLY IK**

but I end up with `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'` as an error.

Then I found this answer [Python - get text from CSS property “content” on a ::before pseudo element in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62775924/13932990)

but I couldn't understand how to edit such code in order to help my case (I know nothing in Javascript)

Comment: simple xpath and xpath locator with .text method isn't working for you?

Comment: not returning anything but selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your selector is correct the result is a `list`, so you need to iterate over it

Get rid of the `.text` at the end of your element and iterate over it instead to grab the `text` values

```
for name in actorName1:
    print(name.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actornames= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class[contains(.,'ipc-metadata-list-item')]]")
for x in range(len(actornames)):
Actorname=actornames[x].text
```

Comment: Error message

```
for x in range(actornames.size):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size' 
```

Comment: .size is used in java , it should be len() in python. Changed it pls check now

Comment: @JD2775 i dont think actornames is list of string because driver.find_elements_by_xpath return Webelement type. You need not to be mean to others just to prove your answer correct. Since a tag has list of elements so I tried to get it by driver.find_elements_by_xpath and then through for loop iterarting i tried to get the text from each element

Comment: @Sonali, sorry, wasn't trying to be mean.  Ok, but wouldn't `Actorname` just keep getting overwritten each loop in your solution?  I thought the goal was to print the text out from all 3 elements. In your example it would only print out the last one.

Comment: @JD2775 yes, it would overwrite and I didn't write the fullfledged code as I don't know how he is going to use it further like print one by one all actor names or put an if condition and if the actor name is matching then do something else. I just gave an idea of how to fetch the actor names in a tag

Comment: @Sonali, your answer worked as well, but with the CSS selector in the thread, you just need to add : at the end of the "for" line and indent the line below it