# How to use Puppeteer to copy text after the ::before psuedo-element?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, dom, puppeteer

I am new to webscraping and Puppeteer and I'm attempting to learn the selector methods in the library. I am trying to select the text in the following code after the `::before` tag. I also want the text in the span directly after it but the text in the anchor tag is more important.

```
<div class="details-inner">
<a class="trackName playIcon" href="/link/488824/sample-text-%40-link/" title="A Title is Here"> ::before "This is the text I want"</a>
<span class="track"> <a href="/anchor-link-to-somewhere/">I also want this text</a></span>
</div>
```

Another problem is that there are ten other divs on the page that share the class `"trackName"` and `"playIcon"` but I only want the text from the first instance/div that has this class.

My thought process was to select the class and map all of the instances into an Array and grab the first index of the array.

I tried the two following approaches to no avail.

Attempt 1:

```
const content = await page.$$('.trackName playIcon');
const contentText = await page.evaluate(a => a.textContent, content);

console.log(contentText);
```

Attempt 2:

```
const content1 = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trackName playIcon'), a => a.textContent);
});
console.log(content1[0]);
```

I'm not sure if my errors stem from the text being after the psuedo element or if my syntax is just wrong. (Both these code samples return undefined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocking things out a bit and following [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62781104/6243352) yields the following code:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<style>
.trackName:before {
  content: "This is the text I want"
}
</style>
</head><body>
<div class="details-inner">
  <a class="trackName playIcon" href="/link/488824/sample-text-%40-link/" title="A Title is Here">test</a>
  <span class="track"> <a href="/anchor-link-to-somewhere/">I also want this text</a></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const before = await page.$eval(
    ".trackName",
    el => getComputedStyle(el, ":before").content
  );
  const text = await page.$eval(".track", el => el.textContent.trim());
  console.log(before); // => "This is the text I want"
  console.log(text); // => I also want this text
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Selectors automatically grab the first if you use `$` methods rather than `$$` methods.

Your attempts fail because `.trackName playIcon` (find a `<playIcon />` inside of `class="trackName"`) should be `.trackName.playIcon` (find an element `class="trackName playIcon"`).

The first attempt passes an array of element handles but tries to `.textContent` it. Use a `$` or `[0]` to get a singular element which you can `.textContent`.